# Google-Maps-Api Map in Meteor, do not render when placed in a div

Tags: html, css, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am using `dburles:google-maps` package in meteor. It works fine. But as soon as I wrap a div around my map, the div colapses and the map does not render.
eg:
this works fine:

```
{{>map}}

<template name="map" >
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
</template>
```

this does not:

```
<div>
    {{>map}}
</div>
```

this works fine:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100%">
     {{>map}}
 </div>
```

this does not:

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- or div without class or any other class --!>
       <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100%">
           {{>map}}
       </div>
</div>
```

sitting for hours on it now and just can not figure out what the issue is, please help.

Comment: What's the size of the div in Dev Tools?  Maybe Google Maps is there but either too small or even `display:hidden`?

Comment: no size at all... and even if I set it to any size, the size changes, I can see the container adjusting, but maps is not rendered...

Comment: Maybe the div size is 0 when Google Maps API starts, and thus it tries to draw a 0x0 sized map?

Comment: well maybe, but why does this happen only if it is in an extra div? And how do I find that out?

Comment: If I set the outer div to min-height: 100px, map is not rendered anyway... I could cry right now...

Comment: resolved it by setting "height:100px" it was the min-height that was causing the issue, but why?

Comment: Well, I can't tell you for 100% sure, but it seems like Google Maps does some DOM-level updates at run-time.  If the size of the element it is trying to do those dynamic DOM changes to is sized to 0, well, guess what size it will use in all it's dynamic calculations?  And 0 times anything is 0.

Comment: Well I understand, but why does it work with height but not with min-height, that is very strange imo.

Comment: Your assuming Google's code is looking at `min-height`.  It's JavaScript, and would have to be coded to do so.  It may not be, and at the time the DOM is build `height` might be 0.